# Setting up andEngine and andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, andengine

[image]

My Android Studio hierarchy currently looks like this. When I go under the "Project" tab in Android Studio, I can see both andEngine and andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension included. The hierarchy under Project is shown below.

[image]

Is there a way to include this in the actual Android Studio project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up `AndEngine` in Android Studio is slightly trickier than setting ti up in Eclipse.

This is a nice step-by-step overview of how to set up AndEngine right in Android Studio. - [HOW TO SETUP ANDENGINE WITH ANDROID STUDIO](http://www.makethegame.net/android-andengine/how-to-setup-andengine-with-android-studio/)

> The main difference in setup as per the tutorial above is as follows:
>
> Just select “Import existing Project” and choose the Path for the
>   Andengine Eclipse Project. This is the way to import AndEngine into
>   the Project.
>
> You should now “Open Module Settings” and check the “Dependencies”
>   Tab. AndEngine GLES2 should now be added as Module Dependeny.
>
> If it is a Library Dependency – remove the entry and add it as Module
>   Dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other examples & tutorials that have 5-10+ steps, requiring you to download AndEngine from github (sometimes multiple projects) and then configure/setup all yourself locally *(not fun)* ..

Here's a project that very cleverly has the AndEngine setup ready to go as part of the project structure

https://github.com/mutexkid/andengine-androidstudio

Verified to work on OS X 10.11, Android Studio 2.3

The IDE required a few sync/update/refresh calls to configure for current gradle version, etc

If this part is registered without error and the base class is recognized, then you know AndEngine is setup:

`public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity`

Here's a screen shot of the running demo:

[image]

Comment: Setting up AndEngine in Android Studio has been a thorn in my side for a while.  Big Thanks to @mutexkid for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a jar file of andengine and box2d then follow these steps

1. open project in project view
2. copy jar file into libs folder
3. right click on jar file and select add as library